# ChoiceType Not Mapping to Entity Field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have an Announcement Entity that where a `EditAnnouncementType` form is mapped to. I have two other `CheckBoxType` forms that automatically update their respective fields, but the `ChoiceType` form isn't working.

```
$builder
        ->add('edit', SubmitType::class,
            array
            (
                'label' => 'Save changes',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']

            ))

        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'choices' => [
                    'info_type' => 1,
                    'star_type' => 2,
                    'alert_type' => 3,
                    'lightbulb_type' => 3,
                    'event_type' => 4,
                    'statement_type' => 5,
                    'cat_type' => 6,
                    'hands_type' => 7
                ],

                'mapped' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
            ])
```

The Announcement entity and type field

```
class Announcement
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
     private $type;

     /**
     * @return string
     */
     public function getType(): string
     {
        return $this->type;
     }

    /**
    * @param int $type
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function setType(int $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion would be that Symfony somehow strict checks the value (using `===`).
And since your getter returns a `string`, the mapping doesn't happen properly.

You should try fixing your getter:

```
 /**
  * @return int
  */
 public function getType(): int
 {
    return $this->type;
 }
```

Also mind that you might have a problem in your choice array:

```
// be careful: those two have the same value
'alert_type' => 3, 
'lightbulb_type' => 3,
```

This would surely cause an issue to Symfony, especially if it uses `array_values` in order to select the right choice out of the value of your entity.

Comment: fixed the getter to return a int but still doesn't work

Comment: Also: what about the duplicated value 3? (see edited answer)

Comment: accepting this answer although I couldn't replicate exactly why it started working. sometime in between posting this question and now I changed `mapped` to `false`. changing it back to `true` fixed it. The string return didn't matter